# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6 (in.java.lang.String)

Tags: java

Errors out of bounds saying,

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6 (in.java.lang.String)

when I run the code. I am trying to find how many identical characters two strings have in the same spots.

```
Public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countAlike("happy","damp");
}

public static int countAlike(String a, String b) {
    int acount = a.length();
    int bcount = b.length();
    int countAlike = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= bcount; i++){
        for(int l = 0; l <= bcount; i++){
            if(a.substring(i,i+1).equals(b.substring(l,l+1))){
                countAlike += 1;
            }
            else{ 
            }
        }
    }
    return countAlike;
}
```

Comment: `String` index's start at 0, so `for(int i = 0; i <= bcount; i++)` will go out of bounds on the last iteration. Change it to `i < bcount`

Comment: i <= bcount should be i < acount  as well as  l <= bcount shoul be l < bcount

Comment: What should this program actually do? Return the amount of equal characters from `a` and `b`, keeping position in mind?

Comment: Yup, forgot to state that! Screw up on  my part.

Answer (score 1):

3 issues here:

1) Change `<= bcount` to `< bcount`.

2) In your 2nd for loop , you are doing `i++` but it should be `l++`

3) The condition in you first `for` loop should be `i < acount`, not `i<bcount`

Answer (score 1):

Indexes for String characters in Java like in most languages start with 0, therefore, the last index of the strings actually is `str.length() - 1`.

When you test with `<=`, your variable is incremented until the value is equal to your length, which is an out of bound index.

Rather test with `<` for both of your tests. Your variable will stop after the last character of that string instead of trying one last time with an index that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this code it will return 3, not sure if that is what you expected for the return value. You have to change a few things

1. First for loop `for(int i = 0; i < acount; i++)`
2. Second for loop `for(int l = 0; i < bcount; l++)`

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args){

       System.out.println(countAlike("happy","damp"));
   }

   public static int countAlike(String a, String b){

       int acount = a.length();
       int bcount = b.length();
       int countAlike = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < acount; i++){
           for(int l = 0; l < bcount; l++){
               if(a.substring(i,i+1).equals(b.substring(l,l+1))){
                   countAlike += 1;
                   }
               else{}
           }
       }
       return countAlike;
   }
   ```

If you have a `System.out.println(a.substring(i, i+1));` and `System.out.println(b.substring(l, l+1));` in your If statement in the for loop if will print out `a a p p p p`.